# How to store all the checked checkboxes class name in an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

I am trying to store all the checked checkboxes class names in an array to parse it using an ajax function later.

But first to make sure that all the classes being stored in the array correctly I alert them, but know, what I see is just the first checked checkbox class

there supposed to be many as the check boxes are generated dynamically .

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#actselect').change(function() {
      var conceptName = $( "#actselect option:selected" ).attr ( "id");
      if (conceptName == "payall"){
     var checkedB = new Array();
         checkedB.push($("input.NP:checkbox:checked").attr("class"));
     alert(checkedB);
  }

});
```

**HTML**

```
   a php while loop {

    <input type="checkbox"  value="None" id="itemselectNP" class="NP T<?php echo $productId; ?>" name="itemselect" />

   }
```

Please  let me what is wrong with my code? I have tried different solutions poped on google search but still no luck.

Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** to trace multiple element right now it pick only one checkbox so use each to store all of their class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#actselect').change(function() {
      var conceptName = $( "#actselect option:selected" ).attr ( "id");
      if (conceptName == "payall"){
     var checkedB = new Array();
         $("input.NP:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
           checkedB.push($(this).attr("class"));
         });
     alert(checkedB);
  }

});
```

Comment: rattan your answer is so simple and so workable, thanks a lot, It will be appreciated if you could vote up my questions too. :)

Comment: someone down voted me again for no reason, could you help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $array = [];

$.each($('input[type= checkbox]:checked'),function(i,val){
    $array.push('your want to push the value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
    var checkedB = new Array();
    $("input :checkbox:checked").each(function (){
           checkedB.push($(this).attr('class'));
    }) ;
    alert(checkedB);
```

Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function() {

      GetSelectedCheckbox();
    $('#btnGet').click(function(){
        GetSelectedCheckbox();
    });
    $('#btnSave').click(function() {
            addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
        });
    });
    function GetSelectedCheckbox()
    {
    var checkedB = new Array();
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if(this.checked)
        {
            //alert($(this).attr('class'));
            checkedB.push($(this).attr("class"));
        }

     });
    alert(checkedB);
    }
    function addCheckbox(name) {
       var container = $('#checkDiv');
       var inputs = container.find('input');
       var id = inputs.length+1;

       $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name,class:'class'+id }).appendTo(container);
       $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
    }
      </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u8sRb/